# How to pass variables between templates - ARM json

Tags: json, templates, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm looking for a way to pass a variable (normal string) from a linked template back up to my main template.

I want to use something like: (in linked template)

```
 "outputs": {
  "installStringNodes": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[variables('installString').value]"
  }
}
```

And then i want to call this variable into my main template. But i can't seem to crack how.

```
"variables":{
   "installStringFromNodeResources": {
      "value": "[??('node-resources')??.outputs.installStringNodes.value]"
    },
}
```

There's a 'sharing state in resource manager templates' doc with the usage of reference() but apparently that can't be used in variables as it gives me an error while trying to deploy.
Seems to me there should be an easy solution for this but i haven't been able to see it yet..

Answer (score 2):

In the main template, the variable should be:

`"installStringFromNodeResources": {
      "value": "[reference('node-resources').outputs.installStringNodes.value]"
    }`

Follow this walk through [sharing state between templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-resource-manager-state/)