# Sharing variables, or constants, between ARM templates

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I was thinking to either define API version numbers it looks like I keep repeating in some template referenced in all of linked templates, but it looks as if I have trouble doing so and I'm not sure if this should be even possible let alone how to do it.

For instance, int `azuredeploy-shared.json` I could do something like

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "variables": {
    "apiVersion": {
        "resources": { "deployments": "2015-01-01" }
    }
  }
}
```

and in `azuredeploy.json` I could then use it like

```
resources": [
{
    "name": "someResource",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion').resources.deployments]",
```

The first stumbling block is there needs to be a `resources` section. It makes me wonder if I reference a wrong *schema* or should one be referenced at all. If I create something I regard as dummy resources and provided this idea works, how should the `azuredeploy.json` reference this file?

I could do something like `"[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/ProjectName/Templates/azuredeploy-shared-json', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]"` but I don't know where or how and should it still work. So, working pointers appreciated in this regard. I did saw [How to pass variables between templates - ARM json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772904/how-to-pass-variables-between-templates-arm-json), but unfortunately I didn't understand how should it work and neither the linked Azure example.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your scenario... are you essentially trying to pull parametrers/variables from 2 json files - one with the shared values and one with values unique to that deployment?

Comment: @bmoore-msft I'm trying to create a file "constants", which I can "include" in other files and then reference the constants with some constant variable name. I noticed I have a lot of strings such as "apiVersion": "2015-01-01", which I'd like to update at once once the tooling doesn't complain, say, in this case about using *"2016-03-30"*. I'm afraid I've missed something simple. I've managed to "include" other fragments (using that `concat` thing there) and pass parameters to them, but not *from them*. Maybe I should somehow utilize the `outputs` directive..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think you could do this using deployment output... it seems like there might be a simpler solution but I can't think of one for as much as I understand about your scenario.

1) deploy a template containing all your constants and set those constants as outputs for that deployment

2) in the template deployment where you want to access them, use the reference function, eg

```
reference('/subscriptions/{GUID}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/{deploymentName}','2015-01-01').outputs.{nameOfConstant}.value]"
```

Just deploy step #1 again with the same deployment name to update the constants.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: I think outputs is the way to go. I've grown my template quite big, so need to break down it a bit and test. Thanks for confirming this!

Comment: It might not be feasible if it contains secrets.

Comment: For secrets you would use keyVault - also, since the OP azure app config store is available for these types of scenarios: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview